# Computer will not turn off and a black screen is showing

Tags: windows

My computer will not turn off, i unplugged it but when i plug it back in it just turns back on without me pressing the power button. It is also only showing a black screen on the monitor.

Comment: By computer, do you mean you have a laptop?

Comment: No a desktop. It is old and i can not get to the system properties because the monitor screen is connected but blank. It runs windows xp and has a intel pentium 4 ht

Comment: No display means you usually need to listen for beep codes during boot . . . though you'll need to know what the BIOS on the motherboard was.  http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Comment: I already tried to access the bios but it wont let me. But i did notice that it beeped when it was plugged back in

Comment: How do i figure out what BIOS it has

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your monitor is working ok? (if you power off the desktop do you see any message on the monitor, is the menu appearing on the screen if you press the MENU button)

If yes, try to remove individual component from your PC to see if your motherboard beeps (start with the RAM, then HDD etc). If you remove the RAM and don't hear any beeps that your motherboard might be the problem).

If your monitor is still black and the tests above went ok you should try the video card. If it is onboard try with an external one to see if it works.

Hope this is helpful.